# tkinter: why images are not dysplayed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

f1=Frame(root)
for img,rlf in [ ('woman',RAISED),('mensetmanus',SOLID),
    ('terminal',SUNKEN), ('escherknot',FLAT),
    ('calculator',GROOVE),('letters',RIDGE)]:
        filename = img + ".gif"
        img1 = PhotoImage(file= filename)
        Label(f1, image = img1, relief=rlf).pack(side=LEFT,
            padx=5)
f1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Could you help me understand why this excerpt produces 5 empty places for images (though borders are drawn correctly according to what was meant), and 1 image. The last image (which is visible)  is letters. And it seems to be cropped from  than its actual size. My letters.gif contains letters from A to G, but this code displays only from half B to half F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, i think, because img1 is overwritten in each loop. You need to keep references to image objects somewhere, so that garbage collector wont trash them:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

f1=Frame(root)
img_list = []                  #<-- store references to images
for img,rlf in [ ('woman',RAISED),('mensetmanus',SOLID),
    ('terminal',SUNKEN), ('escherknot',FLAT),
    ('calculator',GROOVE),('letters',RIDGE)]:
        filename = img + ".gif"
        img1 = PhotoImage(file= filename)
        img_list.append(img1) #<-- store references to images
        Label(f1, image = img1, relief=rlf).pack(side=LEFT,
            padx=5)
f1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, images have started to display. But the last image is still cropped. Maybe the result is that the whole picture has reached the  screen limits? If I delete one image from the middle of the list, everything is correct.

Comment: Cool. Maybe because your relief? I dont know why its cropped, without actually seeing what is happening.

Comment: No, I've just deleted anything about relief. The same crop. But the width of the whole frame fits the screen perfectly. The last image is centered and cropped.

Comment: Maybe make new question, and provide screenshot what is happening.